# IBM System x3400 M2 alert display

Tags: ibm

My server, IBM System x3400 M2, is alarming in displaying an amber "!" exclamation.
I have not have configured the management port.

Is there any software to identify this alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the IBM Director, You also can run IBM Dynamic System Analysis (DSA). This program can capture your hardware logs

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [IBM Director](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/director/pubs/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.director.status.helps.doc/fqm0_c_viewing_health_and_status.html) installed, you could simply check the system health view to figure out what's wrong.

Other than that, check the BIOS setup utility for the *"System Event/Error Log"* which latest entries should give you an idea about the cause of the alert. If the fault has been transient, clearing the log might clear the alert too.